# Getting an average measurement based on two raters for cases where data is missing for one rater

Tags: spss, missing-data, data-imputation

#### Context:

I'm investigating behaviour in a clinical study involving children. I had both parents and teachers completing  questionnaires to inform an understanding of the same underlying constructs, for example reactive aggression.

At the conclusion of data collection I have parent data in all cases, n=55, and teacher data for 41 cases - therefore, I have 14 cases where I only have the parent data.

For the purposes of our study it makes sense to aggregate parent and teacher observations for each case. As I have a small sample and I do have parent data for every case, deleting cases in a pairwise manner does not seem a viable option. There are several variables for which I need to do this, all of which seem to correlate well. Before aggregating data, I thought it would make sense to address the missing data issue.

With regards to 'substituting' I have done some brief reading and am familiar with the basic 'within variable' substitution options, however, I thought there may be a more powerful method available where I could use:

(a) the parent score we have in every case for every variable, n=55, 100% of cases.

(b) our understanding of the relationship between parent and teacher scores in cases where we have both, n=41, 74.5% of cases

#### Question:

- Does the general idea outlined above seem reasonable?
- What would be a good algorithm for implementing it in detail?
- How could it be implemented in SPSS?

Answer (score 4):

The idea above sounds rather like single imputation. This is a better idea when faced with missing data than either list-wise or pair-wise deletion.  However, its still not a good approach.

A better approach could be multiple imputation. Essentially, you simulate from 3-10 datasets conditional on your observed data. You then perform all of your analyses on each of these datasets, and combine the results at the end. The purposes in the simulation of multiple datasets is to ensure that the uncertainty in the imputation process is accounted for.

This can be done using the Multiple Imputation procedure in SPSS (i believe its on the analyze menu).

However, while multiple imputation has been shown to be valid with large datasets, there is not as much information on its use in small samples.

A good introduction (from an educational perspective) can be found [here](http://www.csos.jhu.edu/contact/staff/jwayman_pub/wayman_multimp_aera2003.pdf)

A paper on its use in small samples (in a longitudinal context) can be found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16220515)